# How can show pop when user typing using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, validation

I want to create a function for showing pop or status when user typing something in field, I want to do it without submitting form, I have try following function but its not working properly can anyone let me know where the problem..........?

### Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('confirm').addEventListener('change', checkFile, false);
approveletter.addEventListener('change', checkFile, false);

function checkFile(e) {
        if ($('#confirm').val().length > 0) {

            alert("txt");
        }
    }
</script>
```

### HTML

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="confirm">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just listen to the `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` events.  I included a jsfiddle that might help.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1L3g68q5/5/)

Comment: take a look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/ec0oka1o/. Now even if you type in textbox1, the 'edit' highlights to only one function instance. can you please tell me how to segregate those or have multiple instances of 'change' function. I mean for each textbox one new instance of change function, independent of the other instances.

Comment: @mario23: Would you like the solution to be written in jQuery or in pure JavaScript?

Comment: @Luka I would like to do it in pure JS, but using jquery is also fine, as I'm already using it to POST. Acrually, I tried in JS but only one instance is getting created, that works in one textbox but not on others.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit - The Latest Update**

Okay, I see you've got your fiddle from Vivek, but you might be interested in this as well. Now I get completely what you want to achieve, and here's a short description. The best practice is to split JavaScript from HTML and avoid putting JavaScript inside HTML `head` and `body` as much as you can.

So, first create three files: `Test.js` `Example.html` and `Test.css`.  Of course, you also need jQuery file which you just include here inside the head. In `Example.html` put the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Test.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Test.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="test"/><span id="popup"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

In `Test.css` add some style to your pop-up span element (you could also use division element and style it to your liking if you want fixed height and width, add shadows and so on):

```
#popup {

    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    display: none;

}
```

And finally, put the following JavaScript code in `Test.js`:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $("#test").keyup( function() {

        if($("#test").val().length>5) {

            $("#popup").fadeIn();
            $("#popup").html("Invalid length. Maximum is 5.");

        }
        else {

            $("#popup").fadeOut();

        }

    });

});
```

By dividing JavaScript, CSS and HTML into separate files, you get much tidier HTML and separated styling and client-side logic from markup.

**Old Answer**

Wrap the code inside `$(document).ready()`.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    document.getElementById('confirm').addEventListener('change', checkFile, false);
    approveletter.addEventListener('change', checkFile, false);

});

function checkFile(e) {

    if ($('#confirm').val().length > 0) {

        alert("txt");

    }
}
```

Also, `addEventListener` is not available in IE8 and below. You could use the `onchange` event, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    document.getElementById("confirm").onchange = checkFile;

});
```

There is a similar method for IE8 and earlier called `attachEvent`. In case of using the `attachEvent` method, it would look something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    document.getElementById('confirm').attachEvent('change', checkFile);
    approveletter.attachEvent('change', checkFile);

});
```

You could also use the `jQuery.change()` as suggested in the comments by Protron:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#confirm").change(function() {

        if ($('#confirm').val().length > 0) {

            alert("txt");

        }

    });

});
```

And of course it's possible to do it without the classic alert pop-up window. You could create your own HTML division element with `display:none` and show it when necessary. Just send me a note in the comments if you need instructions on that as well.

Comment: its working when I click on web page, it this possible without clicking its alert.

Comment: I'm writing a small tutorial for you. I'll let you Know when I've put it online.

Comment: OK please i'm waiting

Comment: @AyazShah: I see you've already got your fiddle, this might be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using this, you **need not** click the web page.

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="confirm"><br /><br />
<span id="status" ></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#confirm').keyup(function () {
        if ($('#confirm').val().length > 0) {
            $('#status').html("Text entered");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#status').html("Text removed");
        }
    }
)
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide me Jsfiddle..?